# Unpacking multiple arguments in pytest

Tags: python, dictionary, pytest

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988664/define-a-pytest-fixture-providing-multiple-arguments-to-test-function) question that has no answer. The OP asks to unpack several variables (using pytest fixtures) and make them have their local name available to the testing function. I thought I had a clean solution, involving automatic unpacking of a dictionary:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture  
def my_fix():
    return {"A" : 4, "B": 6 }


def test_something(my_fix):
    locals().update(my_fix)

    assert A == 4
    assert B == 6
```

This is inspired by [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-make-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary-into-variables-in-Python) answer in Quora. When I run this test using pytest, it fails, because there seems to be no local variables called `A` or `B`!

Anyone willing to shed some light on why this happens? Also, an answer to the original question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These links might help. The official docs say you cannot reliably modify locals().  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: @TravisBlack I think not. From the docs it seems that pytest automatically calls my_fix. Also you can modify the code and see python returns an error - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

Comment: I actually do not get that error, but I never got an error with your code either.  The only error I get is if I try to update with my_fix instead of my_fix:  TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable.  Probably has to do with python or pytest version.  python 2.7 here.  says pytest 1.4.29 i think?

Comment: @TravisBlack weird. Mine is Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.5.0 so that might be the reason...